# Send data to served with Jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am learning jquery.ajax but I cant understand something

```
<html>
<head>
<title>the title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#driver").click(function(event){
       var cacat = $("#nam").val();
      $("#stage").load('/jquery/result.php', {"name":cacat} );
      alert(cacat);
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Enter your name and click on the button:</p>
    <input type="input" id="nam" size="40" /><br />
    <div id="stage" style="background-color:blue;">
    STAGE
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="driver" value="Show Result" />
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the Php FIle

```
<?php
if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
{
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
  echo "Welcome ". $name;
}
?>
```

I don't understand what is this `$("#stage").load('/jquery/result.php',{"name":cacat});`
because it's also working with `$("#stage").load('result.php', cacat );`

So here comes the question:
What's the difference between `{"name":cacat}` and `cacat`? Also both scripts do the same thing, the jQuery gets the value of the input and the PHP also gets the value of the input, why so?

Comment: Have you red the doc on `.load()` ? It seems that you need to use `.ajax()` instead. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I am following a tutorial , can you please suggest why use `.ajax()` instead of `.load()` ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the first one sends a JSON object which gets to `$_REQUEST` whereas the other one sends the value, without the JSON form.

Comment: No, the difference is that `.load()` only loads things, It does'nt send any data or variable to the server.

Comment: Indeed , you are right but i had some problem with my apache server and it wouldnt upload my file so it showed me the same result.
The jsonObject is a (key,value) object , so the key has to be the same as the input id? and the result of `$_REQUEST[ ' key ' ] would be the value.
Please correct me if i am wrong.